# Graph API gives empty response in Power Automate HTTP element

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am trying to get the drive-ids of a SharePoint site. In order to do that I use the following element:

[image: Power Automate http element]

The URI is in the form of:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com:xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/drives

The result is this (status code 200):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}
```

When I try exactly the same URI in Graph Explorer, I get this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2022-10-16T00:17:42Z",
            "description": "",
            "id": "b!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-01-04T05:44:57Z",
            "name": "Documents",
            "webUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxxx/Shared%20Documents",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "x.x@xxxx.xxx",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "x x"
                    }
            },
            "owner": {
                "group": {
                    "email": "xxxxxxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxx"
                }
            },
            "quota": {
                "deleted": 1794912,
                "remaining": 27487786218381,
                "state": "normal",
                "total": 27487790694400,
                "used": 2681107
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Both applications have the following permissions:

- Files.ReadWrite.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All

Can anyone tell me why I am getting different results in the two applications? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jleture I had another look at my permissions and it turned out I was using delegated permissions instead of application permissions. Changing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The URI must be:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/drives`

(with coma)

But your screenshot shows something different, with colon, like:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/drives`

I try with my environment and it's working fine:

[image: HTTP sites drives]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately the result is exactly the same: it works in Graph Explorer, but Power Automate gives me an empty array as the result.

Comment: The difference may be the permissions of the app registration. I'm using the Microsoft Graph application permission Sites.FullControl.All and not the (old) SharePoint permissions (Sites.ReadWrite.All)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Because of your comment I had another look at my permissions and it turned out I was using delegated instead of application permissions. Changing that solved the problem.